# EF Core: How to include a common column in all generated migrations?

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, table-per-type

**Note**: an answer in either VB.NET or C# will be fine. I have no preference.

I'm using table-per-type architecture.

I want all of my entities to have a second key column (of type `Guid`), so I've created a base class like this:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Entity
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Key As Guid
End Class

Public Class City
    Inherits Entity

    Public Property Name As Integer
    Public Property Code As String
End Class
```

I want each of these columns to self-populate at the database level (SQL Server) when a new row is added, so I've created a configuration like this:

```vb
Public Class EntityConfiguration
  Implements IEntityTypeConfiguration(Of Entity)

  Public Sub Configure(Builder As EntityTypeBuilder(Of Entity)) Implements IEntityTypeConfiguration(Of Entity).Configure
    Builder.Property(Function(Entity) Entity.Key).IsRequired.HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")
  End Sub
End Class
```

This works—the column is added correctly—but the migrations generator builds code for one table only, named `Entities`.

I tried this in my `CityConfiguration` class:

```vb
Builder.ToTable("Cities")
```

...but the generator still includes an `Entity` table. This is undesirable for obvious reasons. `Entity` is a base class only. And the `Key` column is omitted from the `Cities` table.

Is there a way to have all of my entities contain this common `Key` column without having to include an explicit call to `HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")` in each entity's configuration? That's going to be tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, shucks... that didn't take long.

A quick-and-dirty extension method gets us there just nicely:

```vb
Public Module Extensions
  <Extension>
  Public Sub AddKey(Of TEntity As Entity)(Builder As EntityTypeBuilder(Of TEntity))
    Builder.Property(Function(Entity) Entity.Key).IsRequired.HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")
    Builder.HasIndex(Function(Entity) Entity.Key).IsUnique()
  End Sub
End Module
```

And then we just call it like this in each entity's configuration:

```vb
Builder.AddKey
```

I'll leave this Q&A up in case anyone wants to use the idea.

**--EDIT--**

Possibly even cleaner would be to use a base class:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class BaseConfiguration(Of T As Entity)
  Public Overridable Sub Configure(Builder As EntityTypeBuilder(Of T))
    Builder.Property(Function(Entity) Entity.Key).IsRequired.HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")
    Builder.HasIndex(Function(Entity) Entity.Key).IsUnique()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Just make sure it doesn't implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration(Of Entity)`, or an unwanted `Entity` table will be generated.

Use it like this:

```vb
Public Class CityConfiguration
  Inherits BaseConfiguration(Of City)
  Implements IEntityTypeConfiguration(Of City)

  Public Overrides Sub Configure(Builder As EntityTypeBuilder(Of City)) Implements IEntityTypeConfiguration(Of City).Configure
    Builder.Property(Function(City) City.Code).IsRequired.HasDefaultValue(String.Empty).HasMaxLength(7)
    Builder.Property(Function(City) City.Name).IsRequired.HasDefaultValue(String.Empty).HasMaxLength(25)

    Builder.HasIndex(Function(City) City.Code).IsUnique()
    Builder.HasIndex(Function(City) City.Name)

    MyBase.Configure(Builder)
  End Sub
End Class
```